# Rust macro to generate builder methods for array of enum

Tags: rust

Say I have a enum like so:

```rust
enum Option {
    A,
    B(String),
    C(usize)
}
```

and a struct that holds a number of options:

```rust
#[derive(Default)]
struct Options {
    options: Vec<Option>
}
```

I want to write a macro that generates builder methods for that struct based on the enum variants:

```rust
   // I want the macro to generate these methods
   Options::default()
        .a()
        .b(String::from("Hey"))
        .c(123);
```

I've seen crates like [derive_builder](https://crates.io/crates/derive_builder), but I'm not sure it works for this particular example.

Comment: You can't really do that with a derive macro (at least not generically without manual intervention), because it won't know `A`, `B`, or `C` are variants of `Option` let alone what types they contain.

Comment: Would it be possible with a different kind of macro? I tried using [syn](https://docs.rs/syn/latest/syn/), but it was too hard for me at my current level.

Comment: It is possible write this with a proc macro, but I don't really see an use case for this. If you call this methods explicitly why not just have method `add_option` that takes an `Option` and appends it to a vec?

Comment: My goal is not *having* to remember to add a new method every time I touch the enum. I want the compiler to either remind me of that with type checks or let it write those methods for me (with macros).

Comment: I think you misunderstand Aleksander. `Options` could have a method `fn add_option(mut self, opt: Option) -> Self`. Then you can call it like `Options::default().add_option(Option::A).add_option(Option::B(String::from("Hey"))).add_option(Option::C(124))`. No need to ever touch it again.

Comment: I see! Yup, that's enough for what I wanted. Arguably not as nice, but KISS!

Answer (score 0):

You could create a macro that goes on the enum.

```rs
#[consume(Consumer)]
enum Option {
    A,
    B(String),
    C(usize)
}
```

This would expand into a trait.

```rs
trait Consumer: Sized {
    fn consume(self, opt: Option) -> Self;
    fn a(self) -> Self {
        self.consume(Option::A)
    }
    fn b(self, b: String) -> Self {
        self.consume(Option::B(b))
    }
    fn c(self, c: usize) -> Self {
        self.consume(Option::C(c))
    }
}
```

Then you could implement this trait for `Options`.

```rs
impl Consumer for Options {
    fn consume(mut self, opt: Option) -> Self {
        self.options.push(opt);
        self
    }
}
```

You could do something like [thiserror](https://docs.rs/thiserror/) to add documentation to the methods by adding attributes to each variant. You might be able to reuse doc comments on the variants as documentation on the methods, but I'm not sure.

For simple types, [derive_builder](https://docs.rs/derive_builder/) can generate a builder without any of these types/traits.